# how to make -1(only for date ) from given date in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, exception

given `date = 05-01-2021`

Convert.ToDateTime(process.inorDate).AddDays(-1)

this is starting date  05-01-2021
the end date should be +12 months and -1. which means

Start = 05-01-2021
End = 04-30-2022

just doing -1 for date and updating year

Comment: Remove the `new DateTime()` - it is not needed

Comment: What's the purpose of `new DateTime( )` around it? Where is the `long` variable involved?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CKwTxw

Comment: Also consider `DateTime.TryParse` over `Convert.ToDateTime`

Comment: removing new DateTime() is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the constructors of [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0), there is only 1 which takes a single argument, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_) one. And [`DateTime.AddDays()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.adddays?view=net-5.0) returns a `DateTime` struct. So you're basically doing:

```cs
DateTime converted = Convert.ToDateTime(process.inorDate);
DateTime oneDayBefore = converted.AddDays(-1);
new DateTime(ondeDayBefore);
```

See how it's unnecessary and even impossible to construct a new `DateTime`? Instead just use the `oneDayBefore` variable.